# Generating Rails models, migration and controller code at runtime from from front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, migration, metaprogramming

I am building a web app in ROR for which i need to build a lot of models, joins etc.
But all the models are fundamentally the same, have similar join models to the main item and the migrations are the same. I do not want to keep writing code at the back end, want to generate this at runtime from the front end is it possible.
Eg. All models have the following attributes - id(default), name, exists?
All joins are has_may :through

So from the front end if i define that X is a model and Y is a model and are related at the backend i want to create teh models and migrations. Then i can feed in the data for X, Y and it will be stored in the correct tables.

The controller code is also almost standardized and I would just need to pass in the X,Y and I would want that to go to the controller or be used by it. I mean if X is related to 10 models, then in the controller I need something to iterate over an array containing the names of the 10 relations. So how do i do this. Is there a way of finding out in the controller or in rails all the relations or joins of a model.

What should I look up or study?

Comment: I think your this link will help you http://prelang.com/

Answer (score 0):

My question would be why you need ten models that essentially are the same. And I would have two responses to that:
1.) If its for functionality purposes (i.e. you need 10 models that are perform similar backend functionality) You would want to maybe think about wrapping those models in a module or have them inherit from an abstract model instead of `ActiveRecord:Base`. Do every single one of those models necessarily NEED a migration and their own table in your database? If not, don't generate those migrations. Or give them an object-relational key in your database so that it's a good solid architecture.

2.) If you do need ten models and ten separate tables for those models (that again, are all very similar and *"fundamentally the same"*, you might want to rethink your database architecture. That seems redundant to me personally, and is going to be a huge hassle to maintain. For example, instead of having BlueBaseball, RedBaseball, and GreenBaseball, why not have Baseball, and then give it a type value with the corresponding key value pair being "green", "blue" or "red".

That's just my thinking. Perhaps I don't understand enough about the problem at hand though. Could you explain to us a little more about your models and how your program works in an object oriented architecture?

Comment: I am trying to build a mindmap type of application. Mindmaps consist of nodes and joins. While traditional mindmaps maybe free and unstructured trying to experiment on a functional mindmap. So lets say I am creating a map for Stories. Stories may have various tags like say - Culture, Book, Keywords etc. Under each tag i would give story specific data. So fundamentally the tag model consists only of 2 attributes which might get expanded later - but right now it is Name and Exists. All of the manipulation i want done on the front end in drag and drop.

Comment: So I have following models - Story, Culture, Book, Keyword. All have 2 attributes. Between all I have join tables. Trying to experiment if all of this manipulation can be done from the front end. So the moment I say create a new node like Recipe and say it has following related nodes - Ingredients, Cuisine etc. Again Recipe, Ingredients, Cuisine models will be same. Al will have join tables. Want to keep extending the idea from the front end through drag and drop

Comment: Oh I understand you. So your intention is to actually build something similar to prelang.com ?

Comment: Not really. Just saw the video for prelang. Hopefully something more simple.